# Кастомные ячейки

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple

Доброе время суток, мне нужно сделать что бы в таблице была очень простая кастомная ячейка, а в ней должно быть: Картинка и лейбл, подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Доброе время суток, уважаемый @leonid3452!

Совсем не давно скидывал знакомому, вид самые елементарный:

[image]

Но на сколько я понял, это то, что вам нужно.
Скачать можно тут: [Тут](https://github.com/kovalskiy/iSimpleCustomCell)

Если вам что-то будет не понятно, пишите.

Comment: Спасибо большо, то что нужно!

PS: Тему можно закрыть.

Comment: Я что-то не врублюсь, а чем не устроила стандартная ячейка? Если только расположением элементов - то это надо было менять не введением новых элементов (как я понял через ксиб в сториборде?), а перестановкой старых в наследнике в методе layoutSubviews

Answer (score 1):

aknew прав, стандартная селка поддерживает данную коснтрукцию из коробки.

```
[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Участники форума уже дали ответ на этот вопрос. Чтобы у Вас в будущем не возникало вопросов, я оставлю [здесь](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW1) эту ссылку.
А если прочитаете еще и [это](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) и [это](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10) так все будете знать сам и вообще будете молодец!

Смысл в том что большинство типов ячеек уже есть в системе как предустановленные, вам только нужно выбрать какая Вам больше подходит. Дополнительные элементы рисуются поверх ячейки на `accessoryVIew`, можно также менять положение элементов в ячейках используя проперти frame и метод `-layoutSubviews` через `-setNeedsLayout` . То есть если изучить вопрос, то обнаружится что делать кастомные ячейки на самом деле нужно очень редко, только когда уж очень специфическая задача.